# name textfield made mandatory then UIAlert stopped working

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-authentication

I added a line of code so that name text-field is mandatory when registering an account with firebase but when I did that the UIAlert broke. It stopped showing up when I added that line of code. The code I added is highlighted with a >. What is the best way to fix the problem? Either recode the mandatory name text-field or recode the UIAlert. Which is the simplest way?

```
        @IBAction func registerTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        let namec = nameTextField.text
         if let email = emailTextField.text, let pass = passwordTextField.text, let name = (namec?.capitalized.isEmpty)! ? nil:namec?.capitalized {
            FIRAuth.auth()?.createUser(withEmail: email, password: pass, completion: { (user, error) in
                if user != nil {
                    //user found

                    let interval = NSDate().timeIntervalSince1970
                    let date = Date(timeIntervalSince1970: interval)
                    let dateFormatter = DateFormatter()
                    dateFormatter.dateFormat = "dd/MM/yyyy/HH/mm/SS"
                    // you can change the date format to whatever you wants
                    let dateString = dateFormatter.string(from: date)
                    print(dateString)
                    self.refD?.child("Users").child((user?.uid)!).setValue(["Email": email, "Name": name, "User Created": dateString])
                    print("User Created And Added To Database", email, name, dateString)
                    self.performSegue(withIdentifier: "registertologin", sender: self)
                }
                else {
                    print(error!)
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error Creating Account ", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
                    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
                    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
                }
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i think you have to add alert code in the main queue block because your code is inside a completion handler block

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    print(error!)
    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Error Creating Account ", message: "\(error!.localizedDescription)", preferredStyle: UIAlertControllerStyle.alert)
    alert.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "Dismiss", style: UIAlertActionStyle.default, handler: nil))
    self.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Try this!

Comment: that worked but there has to be text in the name textfield before it pops up

Comment: yes, you just have to put this thing in your else condition